# How to copy a file from SFTP to S3bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, jsch

I am new to coding.I wants to copy a file from SFTP server to S3bucket.I don't want to copy it in to my local..I am trying to do this in Java springboot.Is there any way to do this.Could someone please help me with some code snippet to do the same.

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org). It's an integration library supporting [S3](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/aws2-s3-component.html) and [SFTP](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/sftp-component.html).

Comment: Ok.is it possible to transfer without getting into local